# Unable to load Bootstrap tooltip via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

i'm trying to load (via Ajax Call) a tooltip whose title is in HTML tags. In the first page load when it is loaded by the `include_once` function, the tooltip works fine, but not when i trigger the page load with Ajax Call. Here are my files :

*loadTable.php*

```
    <?php
        $content = "<a data-toggle='tooltip' data-html='true' title='<strong>ok</strong>'
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-align-left'></span></a>";

        echo $content;
    ?>
```

*mypage.php*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadPage()">Load</button>
<div id="tableData">
    <?php include_once('loadTable.php');?>
</div>
```

*myjavascriptfile.js*

```
function loadPage(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadTable.php",
        data:{
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#tableData").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NB: of course i have simplified the example at the extreme, just for understanding and simplicity purposes.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't load? It looks like you're loading the same HTML as you had before.

Comment: Yes it is the same .. But via Ajax, the tooltip doesn't trigger onmouseover the glyphicon.

Comment: You'll need to re-initialize  the tool tips on the dynamically loaded elements

Comment: any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect, see edit , you'll want something like $('.tooltip').tooltip(); after you update the html I'm not 100% on the syntax and I'm on my phone now but IIRC that is the correct ode but you'll need the adjust the selector as needed to target your tooltip elements

Comment: OH it Worked !!! Thank's Mate :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to DelightedD0D, the solution is to re-initialize the tooltips after Ajax Call.

In my case, i added this line :
**$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();**

```
function loadPage(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadTable.php",
        data:{
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#tableData").html(result);
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope it helps others who have the same problem.